# Error running app after adding selenium library to my app

Tags: python, flutter, selenium-webdriver, flet

I am trying to build a windows app.

I added **selenium** library to my app. It runs well before building(using 'flet run' command).

But it fails after building windows app(using 'flet build windows').

This is the error message when running .exe file after building.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 40, in <module>
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 229, in run_module
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\JJ\AppData\Local\Temp\serious_python_tempd9e19e95\main.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\JJ\AppData\Local\Temp\serious_python_tempd9e19e95\__pypackages__\flet\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\JJ\AppData\Local\Temp\serious_python_tempd9e19e95\__pypackages__\flet_runtime\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\JJ\AppData\Local\Temp\serious_python_tempd9e19e95\__pypackages__\flet_core\__init__.py", line 178, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\JJ\AppData\Local\Temp\serious_python_tempd9e19e95\__pypackages__\flet_core\page.py", line 65, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\JJ\AppData\Local\Temp\serious_python_tempd9e19e95\__pypackages__\flet_runtime\auth\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\JJ\AppData\Local\Temp\serious_python_tempd9e19e95\__pypackages__\flet_runtime\auth\authorization.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\JJ\AppData\Local\Temp\serious_python_tempd9e19e95\__pypackages__\httpx\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\JJ\AppData\Local\Temp\serious_python_tempd9e19e95\__pypackages__\httpx\_api.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\JJ\AppData\Local\Temp\serious_python_tempd9e19e95\__pypackages__\httpx\_client.py", line 32, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\JJ\AppData\Local\Temp\serious_python_tempd9e19e95\__pypackages__\httpx\_transports\default.py", line 32, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\JJ\AppData\Local\Temp\serious_python_tempd9e19e95\__pypackages__\httpcore\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\JJ\AppData\Local\Temp\serious_python_tempd9e19e95\__pypackages__\httpcore\_api.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\JJ\AppData\Local\Temp\serious_python_tempd9e19e95\__pypackages__\httpcore\_sync\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\JJ\AppData\Local\Temp\serious_python_tempd9e19e95\__pypackages__\httpcore\_sync\connection.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\JJ\AppData\Local\Temp\serious_python_tempd9e19e95\__pypackages__\httpcore\_synchronization.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\JJ\AppData\Local\Temp\serious_python_tempd9e19e95\__pypackages__\trio\__init__.py", line 76, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\JJ\AppData\Local\Temp\serious_python_tempd9e19e95\__pypackages__\trio\_path.py", line 99, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\JJ\AppData\Local\Temp\serious_python_tempd9e19e95\__pypackages__\trio\_path.py", line 116, in Path
  File "C:\Users\JJ\AppData\Local\Temp\serious_python_tempd9e19e95\__pypackages__\trio\_path.py", line 41, in decorator
AssertionError
```

**Flet version (`pip show flet`)**:

Name: flet
Version: 0.20.2
Summary: Flet for Python - easily build interactive multi-platform apps in Python
Home-page:
Author: Appveyor Systems Inc.
Author-email: hello@flet.dev
License: Apache-2.0

**Operating system**:
Windows 11

Comment: I think you may have to ask authors of `flet` if it can work with `selenium`. Maybe `flet` is not ready to work with (so complex) tools like `selenium`. `flet` has issues on GitHub: https://github.com/flet-dev/flet/issues

Comment: now I see you already added this problem to issues on GitHub :)